# Health checks for rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, openshift

What kind of health checks can be configured for rabbitmq in openshift?

I wasn't able to configure `rabbitmqctl` as suggested in [1] or [2] as it delivers errors when used with the images registry.centos.org/centos/rabbitmq or luiscoms/openshift-rabbitmq

Example:

```
$ rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Error: could not recognise command
...
Only root or rabbitmq should run rabbitmqctl
```

[1] https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/pull/174#issuecomment-452002696

[2] https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s/blob/master/examples/k8s_statefulsets/rabbitmq_statefulsets.yaml